# How to draw focus icon with QPainter

Tags: c++, qt

In the project I am working now we already have the left arrow(which can be seen left bottom corner) drawn with QPaint the code is like :

```
const qreal x1 = left ? (rect.left() + 19) : (rect.right() - 19);
const qreal x2 = left ? (rect.left() + 12) : (rect.right() - 12);
const qreal y2 = rect.y() + rect.height() / 2.0;
const qreal y1 = y2 - 8;
const qreal y3 = y2 + 8;
painter->setPen(QPen(InternalStuff::Instance()->GetColor(ILMCTheme::ColorIconInfoBarArrow), 3, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));
const QVector<QPointF> points = QVector<QPointF>() << QPointF(x1, y1) << QPointF(x2, y2) << QPointF(x2, y2) << QPointF(x1, y3);
painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter->drawLines(points);
```

[image]

Now a new mock up is send to me and I have been asked to implement a focus icon which can be seen in top left corner.

Two requests are a bit different for example focus icon is filled with white color.

Now I am thinking creating a square and fill it with white than draw two lines in the middle of it. Is it a good way to go? Did anyone done something like this before and has samples?

Comment: Who provided the mock up?  Presumably they have the icon that you could just use 'as is'.  No?

Comment: I have been told to not use up the icon but do it with the code instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone need something like that the code below created a similar shape to the one at the top left of the picture in the question

```
QRectF newRec = rect;
painter->save();
newRec.setSize( newRec.size() / 20 * 11 );
painter->setBrush(Qt::white);

QColor colorRect( LMCTheme::Instance()->GetColor(InternalStuff::ColorIconInfoBarArrow));
painter->setPen(QPen( colorRect, 3, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));
painter->translate( rect.width()/2, rect.height()/10 );
painter->rotate(45);
painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

painter->drawRect(newRec);
painter->restore();

QColor color(LMCTheme::Instance()->GetColor(InternalStuff::ColorIconInfoBarBackground));
painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter->setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Clear);
painter->setPen(QPen(color, 3, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap));
painter->drawLine( QLine(QPoint(rect.width()/2, rect.height()/10 ), QPoint(rect.width()/2, rect.height() - rect.height()/10 ) ) );
painter->drawLine( QLine(QPoint(rect.width()/10, rect.height()/2), QPoint(rect.width()*9/10, rect.height()/2)) );
```